# Adding text to video

Tags: c#, video-encoding, video-editing

I'm trying to add text to a video. I've been using the [Accord framework](http://accord-framework.net/intro.html) so far, and this is what I currently have:

```
using (var vFReader = new VideoFileReader())
{
    vFReader.Open(@"\video.mp4");

    using (var vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
    {
        vFWriter.Open(@"\video2.mp4", vFReader.Width, vFReader.Height, vFReader.FrameRate, VideoCodec.MPEG4, vFReader.BitRate);

        for (var i = 0; i < vFReader.FrameCount; i++)
        {
            var image = vFReader.ReadVideoFrame();

            var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);

            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.DrawString("Custom text", font, Brushes.White, new Point(vFReader.Width / 2, 25), format);

            graphics.Flush();

            vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(image, (uint)i);
        }
        vFWriter.Flush();
    }
}
```

This is technically working, but the resulting video is in very poor quality compared to the original. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the difference in quality.

Original video:

[image: Original video]

Edited video:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a side-by-side comparison of the input and output videos? Is the quality just as bad if you just save the original image without adding text?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I have added screenshots of the quality difference. Also, the quality is just as bad if I don't edit the bitmap in any way.

Comment: Either the codec that's being used for encoding isn't very good or this is simply a side-effect of re-encoding the video. You might need to bump up the bitrate or find a better codec.

Comment: The original video is probably not uncompressed so each iteration will lose a bit of quality. Here is an extreme example of the same thing happening with Jpegs that's basically the same effect but more noticable: https://youtu.be/NzsbjwuWYYI

Comment: Thank you @ManfredRadlwimmer. I tried switching to H264-codec and doubling the bit-rate and the quality is much better now!

Comment: Glad I could help :)